# Best way to access SQL statements and Stored Procedures in a database

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

Where is SQL information such as SQL statements and stored procedures located in a database? And How do I store them in a separate database?

Comment: I don't think this is possible. Why would you want to store the procedures in a different database? And what SQL statements are you referring to?

Comment: Turns out that it is possible- this information can be accessed through system stored procedures that extract database metainformation(including information on user created stored procedures). In SQL Server, there are 2 ways to do this->by querying against the information schema table, or by using the sp_helptext system stored procedure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For MS SQL 2008 Stored Procedures are stored under:

- DatabaseName

  - Programmability

    - Stored Procedures

Answer (score 1):

You can read SQL statements using system stored procedure sp_helptext:

```
declare @t table (RowNumber int identity(1,1), Line nvarchar(4000));

insert @t (Line) exec sp_helptext 'sp_helptext';

select * from @t order by RowNumber;
```

Or to see how sp_helptext does that.

Answer (score 0):

Logically (and generally) all such 'meta' data in the database are treated structurally the same way as user data; the system simply maintains one or more schemas dedicated to system level data.

Physical organization of databases are very much vendor specific e.g. an Oracle 10g database will organize the data on disk in a manner specific to it.  For this case, you are more likely to get concrete feedback if you note which database product you are using.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the information_schema view.

```
select routine_name, routine_definition from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.routines
```